# Chair conformation chirality

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality

[image]

I have two questions regarding this solution:

1. I can't see how the structure drawn is the enantiomer.
2. How do I rotate the ring inversion chair form to obtain the enantiomer?

Comment: There's something wrong here because the two conformations are not mirror images.

Answer (score 1):

1.) The mirror plane is orthogonal to the green line drawn between the respective center of the two enantiomers.

2.) The rotation is around the red axis. The red marked carbon atom shows the rotation angle.

[image]